# a plural 's' is added to table title in new version

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to upgrade sequelize to v5.8.10 and sequelize-typescript to v1.0.0-beta.3.
In the new versions, table names seem to be pluralized. How to return to old behavior?

I posted here: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11083
with no answer

```
const dbUser = await User.scope("auth").findOne({ where: { email: "john@domain.com" } });
```

expected result:

```
SELECT "id", "email" FROM "User" AS "User" WHERE ("User"."email" = 'john@domain.com');
```

actual result:

```
SELECT "id", "email" FROM "Users" AS "User" WHERE ("User"."email" = 'john@domain.com');
```

and of course, sql error:

```
ERROR:  relation "Users" does not exist
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is now an option when creating a Sequelize object:

```
define: {
freezeTableName: true   //prevent sequelize from pluralizing table names
},
```